# Making REST Service call with ICS

Tags: rest, delphi

I am trying to make a REST service call with ICS (Overbyte's **I**nternet **C**omponent **S**uite), specifically using TSslHttpCli.  I can make the call if there are no parameters, but cannot determine how to pass parameters. This call works in POSTMAN.

In Delphi Tokyo, I have the following code, and pass the parameters in the BeforeHeaderSend routine.  It should be noted that this is a GET request. I have taken the Google Search JSON sample that ships with ICS as a starting point.

```
procedure TGoogleSearchJsonClientForm.GoogleGetButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
    Zero : byte = 0;
var
    DataStream   : TMemoryStream;
    myString     : String;
begin       
   DataStream                := TMemoryStream.Create;    
   httpCli1.URL := 'https://<URL removed>/csv/csv_file_test';    
   HttpCli1.RcvdStream := DataStream;

      try
            HttpCli1.Get;
            MyString := StreamToString(DataStream);
            DisplayMemo.Lines.Add(MyString);
        except
            on E:Exception do
                Display('Failed. ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
      end;
   ...
  end;
```

I am setting my parameter in the BeforeHeaderSend code...

```
procedure TGoogleSearchJsonClientForm.HttpCli1BeforeHeaderSend(Sender: TObject;
  const Method: string; Headers: TStrings);
begin
  headers.AddPair('DEBUG', 'MY_PARAM');
end;
```

What I am trying to do is emulate this definition from POSTMAN (which works).[image]

The error returned is 'Bad Request'.  Any idea what I am doing wrong? In stepping through the code, it is failing after executing the line "HttpCli1.Get;"

Comment: In POSTMAN, you are sending your `DEBUG` value as an HTTP header. Your Delphi code should match that behavior. Are you sure your `TSslHttpCli` HTTP request actually matches your POSTMAN HTTP request? Have you sniffed the `TSslHttpCli` request at all and compared them for differences? Can you edit your question to show the *RAW* transmitted HTTP requests from both parties? Chances are, the problem has nothing to do with your custom header at all, but some other aspect of the `GET` request that you are not accounting for.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of variables implies usage of the non-https capable client. Use either http without SSL (`http://`) or the SSLHttpClient class.

Comment: Since this started off by using an existing example, I kept the same names as in the sample code.  As per the question description though, "specifically using TSslHttpCli", I am using the SSL version of the http client.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the content-type :

```
HttpCli1.ContentTypePost := 'application/json';
```

And probably your problem comes from this :

```
headers.AddPair('DEBUG', 'MY_PARAM');
```

Try instead :

```
headers.Add('DEBUG: MYPARAM');
```